# Parsing an xml url to display in form of cards

Tags: android, google-glass

I am trying to parse a xml file and display the feeds in form of separate cards. This is what my code looks like till now:

```
package com.bliss.android.helloworld.main;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import com.google.android.glass.app.Card;
import com.google.android.glass.widget.CardScrollAdapter;
import com.google.android.glass.widget.CardScrollView;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class SecondScreen extends Activity {
    ArrayList<Card> headlines = new ArrayList<Card>();
    ArrayList links = new ArrayList();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        new PostTask().execute("http://feeds.pcworld.com/pcworld/latestnews");

        CardScrollView csvCardsView = new CardScrollView(this);
        csaAdapter cvAdapter = new csaAdapter();
        csvCardsView.setAdapter(cvAdapter);
        csvCardsView.activate();
        setContentView(csvCardsView);
    }

    private class PostTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();   
        }    

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String url=params[0];
            try{
                XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
                XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();


                boolean insideItem = false;

                // Returns the type of current event: START_TAG, END_TAG, etc..
                int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
                while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

                        if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                            insideItem = true;
                        } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                            if (insideItem){
                                Card newCard = new Card(SecondScreen.this);
                                newCard.setText(xpp.nextText());
                                headlines.add(newCard); //extract the headline
                            }
                        } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                            if (insideItem)
                                links.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the link of article
                        }
                    }else if(eventType==XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                        insideItem=false;
                    }

                    eventType = xpp.next(); //move to next element
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return url;
        }
    }

    private class csaAdapter extends CardScrollAdapter
    {
        @Override
        public int findIdPosition(Object id)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        @Override
        public int findItemPosition(Object item)
        {
            return headlines.indexOf(item);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return headlines.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position)
        {
            return headlines.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            return headlines.get(position).toView();
        }
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
        try {
            return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I do not get any error but there is nothing displayed on the card. I cant figure out whats the reason. Is it because of Card(SeconScreen.this). But if I dont put that it gives me an error saying constructor not defined.

Comment: Quick sanity check: have you verified the parsing is happening and it is getting to the point where it would create a new card?

Comment: Actually i have passed this particular activity as an intent to my main activity which is just a card. Now that main card appears and onclick the second card also shows up which should ideally have the feed, but there is nothing being displayed. And all this without any errors so i am basically unable to figure out where the problem arises.